# Finding MAX values of two Arrays using MIPS

Tags: arrays, function, mips

I'm supposed to find the max values in two different arrays. Here is an example in C

```
int largest( int* array, int arrayLength) {
    int largest = array[0];
    int index = 1;
    while( index < arrayLength) {
        if( array[index] > largest {
            largest = array[index];
        }
        index++;
    }
    return( largest);
}
```

I'm supposed to do the same by implementing a function in MIPS assembly and test the function in main on two different arrays. I've included my code below, but I'm new and not sure if it even works as I don't have access to QTSPIM on this computer. If you have any suggestions, fixes, or any help at all it is much appreciated. Thanks

```
.data

arrayOne:   .word   -10, 9, 5, 60, 12, -33, 10
arrayTwo:   .word   20, 44, -9, 8, 72, 25, -36

.text
main:

la $s0, arrayOne    #load the array
move $a0, $s0       #move array to register the function can use
jal Largest     #call the function
la $s0, arrayTwo    #load the other array
move $a0, $s0
jal Largest
li $v0, 10  #exit program
syscall

Largest:
addi $sp, $sp, -4   #save return address
sw $ra, 0($sp)

move $t0, $a0   #load array into temp register
lw $v0, 0($t0)  #set maximum to array[0]
li $t2, 1   #set index = 1
Loop:
slt $t3, $t2, $t1   #???
beq $t3, $zero, ExitLoop
sll $t3, $t2, 2     #find offest of next element
add $t3, $t0, $t3   #store address in $t3
lw $t4, 0($t3)      #load next value into $t4
sgt $t5, $t4, $v0   #compare previous max with new value
beq $t5, $zero, notGreater  #jump if not greater

move $v0, $t4   #if greater, set return value to new max

notGreater:
addi $t2, $t2, 1    #increment index
j Loop

ExitLoop:
lw $ra, 0($sp)      #unload the stack
addi $sp, $sp, 4
jr $ra              #return to main
```

Comment: _"I don't have access to QTSPIM on this computer"_ Then getting accesses to a computer where you can run QtSpim, PCSpim, or MARS should be your first priority.

Comment: I tried running it after posting this. It doesn't appear to be working properly. Do you or anyone else have any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong? Or could you point me in the direction I can look?